# Can't get React Component to display onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

I have a `services` component from which I want to call a `serviceData` component

The problem is that on first click of one of the service names, I get `Na` which is the placeholder value for null in `ServiceData` on second click I get an error stating ...

`Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

There is something that is eluding me and I can't quite figure it out.

Fuller Code: https://paste.ee/p/rKNrT

```
class Services extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      services: [],
      servicename: null,
    };
  }
  fetchData(servicename){
    this.setState(() => (
      {servicename: servicename}
    ));

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
      var { clustername } = this.props.match.params;
      if (clustername && typeof clustername !== 'undefined'){
      var u = `https://validapi.com/dev/clusters/${clustername}/services/`
    }
    console.log(u);
    axios.get(u)
    .then( results => {
      let services = results.data.data;
      this.setState(() => ({ services: services }));
      console.log(this.state.services);
    })
    render() {
    const services = this.state.services;
    return (
      <div className="ServiceList">
        <Row>
          <Col sm="3">
        <ListGroup>
      {
        services.map((service) => { return (
          <ListGroupItem key={service + 10} onClick={ () => {this.fetchData(service)} }>{service}</ListGroupItem>) })
      }
    </ListGroup>
  </Col>
          <Col sm="auto">
            {
this.state.servicename ? <ServiceData clustername={this.props.clustername} servicename={this.state.servicename} />: <span>nada</span>
              }

  </Col>

  </Row>
    </div>
    )

  }
}

export default withRouter(Services);
```

Comment: It looks like the `ServiceData` component from the link there isn't wrapped around `withRouter`, like the `Service`. Any component that plans on using router props needs it. Try doing that and see if it works

Comment: As a side note, `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version of react. [See this blog post for why](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), and [see this section on tips for migrating away from it](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change)

Comment: That didn't change much. I did get closer somehow, now the only thing undefined is the servicename.  Thx

Comment: It came down to having to split my url definition in two lines ... thanks